# Spring MVC - Displaying Exception in View (JSP Page)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created an application in Spring MVC for testing the rollback and commit functionality. I am using Transaction using. Here in the service i have created another contact objects without specifying employee id which is a required field. The application works fine when exception is comming while saving and rollback is working.

But the problem is the Exception is printing in my jsp page.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for preventing displaying he exception in te view

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveContact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute("newContact")Contacts contact, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
{
    validator.validate(contact, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {               
        return "newContact";
    }
    contactsDAO.save(contact);
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:viewAllContacts.do";
}
```

**Service**

```
public int save(Contacts contact)
{
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        i = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
        Contacts contacts =new Contacts();
        contacts.setAddress("ABCD");
        contacts.setMobile("8181");
        i = (Integer) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contacts);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return i;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveContact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute("newContact")Contacts contact, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) throws SQLException
{
    validator.validate(contact, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {               
        return "newContact";
    }
    try {
        contactsDAO.save(contact); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("enrtered");
        result.reject("DUPKEY");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "redirect:saveContact.do";
    } 
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:viewAllContacts.do";
}
```

Comment: Check/configure spring exception resolver

Comment: @user3145373ツ Actually as i said i have cretead a exception to check the rollback functionality

Comment: Could you explain what is the exception, if it is the one that you catch in your service (and how it is rethrown then) and what means : *printing in my jsp* ? Does it appears in the middle of the expected page or instead of the expected page ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta see here exception is not the issue, the thing is say we are having some exception during a transaction since i am using `@Transactional` there is no need of defining Transaction explicitly. so when exception occurs it throws out and shows that exception to the user, rather how can i tell user that some thing has went wrong

Comment: @SergeBallesta just the same like [Hibernate, Spring, `@Transactional` - surround with try/catch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379078/hibernate-spring-transactional-surround-with-try-catch) But i am not getting any solution for this, can you please specify some code relevant for the above code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **never** let an exception thrown in service layer arrive directly in user browser. As suggested by Vinit Prajapati you can configure a `HandlerExceptionResolver` that will display appropriate views in case of an exception. You can also have a per controller exception handling mechanisme with one or more `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method(s) that will be fired in case of a configured exception and that can be used almost like `@RequestMapping` annotated methods. At a last ressort you can have explicit try-catch blocks in controller methods.

Extracts from Spring Framework Reference Manual : *You use the @ExceptionHandler method annotation within a controller to specify which method is invoked when an exception of a specific type is thrown during the execution of controller methods ... The @ExceptionHandler value can be set to an array of Exception types. If an exception is thrown matches one of the types in the list, then the method annotated with the matching @ExceptionHandler will be invoked ... Much like standard controller methods annotated with a @RequestMapping annotation, the method arguments and return values of @ExceptionHandler methods are very flexible... The return type can be a String, which is interpreted as a view name or a ModelAndView object.*

In my own code, I use @ExceptionHandler for general errors such as unaccessible database, but use try-catch blocs in controller if I want to deal with exceptions really caused by business rules and for which I prefere to use `<form:errors>` tags in the view, explicitely calling `Errors.reject()` in controller.

EDIT: concrete examples

Suppose you want to display special view in case of `DataIntegrityViolationException`

In controller

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
public ModelAndViewexceptionHandler(Exception ex, Locale locale) {
    String msg = ex.getMessage();
    // or if you have a I18n app : String msg = messageSource.getMessage("DUPKEY", null, locale);
    return new ModelAndView("duplicate", "msg", msg);
}
```

with `"duplicate"`leading to a jsp where `${msg}` will display the exception message. Of course for that to work, your service must throw a DataIntegrityViolationException ...

If you prefere the error to be displayed in normal view, you can do instead

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveContact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute("newContact")Contacts contact, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
{
    validator.validate(contact, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {               
        return "newContact";
    }
    try {
        contactsDAO.save(contact);
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        result.reject("DUPKEY");
        return "newContact";
    }
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:viewAllContacts.do";
}
```

With that last construct you will display the error message corresponding to `DUPKEY` in your configured `MessageSource`bean like other global errors in your jsp view through the tag `<form:errors/>` with no `path` in it.

```
<form:form>
      <%-- Show global errors (notably DUPKEY) --%>
      <form:errors/>
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Address:</td>
              <td><form:input path="address" /></td>
              <%-- Show errors for address field --%>
              <td><form:errors path="address" /></td>
          </tr>
...
</form:form>
```

Comment: Can you show me an example in related to my application as shown above

Comment: here can you please tell me what is the use of `@ExceptionHandler` and its block , since what i feel is that even you have put a try catch within that `contactsDAO.save(contact);` so whenever an exception occurs it will be catched and within that catch block if we return back to the newContact or viewAllContacts views with the corresponding error message

Comment: Just added **instead** at the introduction of the second example. The examples are exclusive : either you use a `@ExceptionHandler` with a view dedicated to exception display, or you use a catch block and keep displaying error in same view.

Comment: that means when some exception occurs if we want to display that to a dedicated common exception view we can use `@ExceptionHandler` otherwise if we want to display within that same view we can return through the catch itself.

Comment: Thanks!!, one more thing , i.e if we want to pass an error message from the catch block to the same view we render, how can we do that through BindingResult or any other way

Comment: I have updates my question within the edit, in that what will i need to do in order to pass a message to the view –

Comment: Not that, see i want to pass/add a message like `ObjectError error=new ObjectError("error", "failed"); result.addError(error);` and in the view  i want to print it, also did'nt get what's this `DUPEKEY`

Comment: You can either add another object to the model (get it as a parameter in you method : `public String create(..., SessionStatus status, Model model)`) `model.addAttribute("error", error)` or simply add the message to the `BindingResult` which allready implements `Errors` via `result.add("FAILED", null, "failed");` - will search FAILED in `MessageSource` and default to string `failed` and display it via `<form:errors/>`.

Comment: In the catch block i defined like this      `catch (Exception ex) { model.addAttribute("error", "failed"); result.reject("DUPKEY"); return "redirect:saveContact.do"; } `  and in the view i did `${error}` but its not printing  anything, is it due to the redirect

Comment: If you are in error block, you shouldn't redirect but simply forward to your view, like you do for validation errors. My example do not redirect from catch block ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55627/discussion-between-alex-man-and-serge-ballesta).

Comment: if i want to pass the error message with the redirect what will i do

Comment: Useless moralizing answer. If I want to display stack traces in the browser, I'm doing that for developers and testers, not for end users in production. Obviously.

Answer (score 4):

Create a base controller class (which your others extend), and for example try this method (although you'll want to handle different errors with different methods, but this will get you started):

```
    /*
 * Default exception handler, catches all exceptions, redirects to friendly
 * error page and send e-mail does not catch request mapping errors
 */
@ExceptionHandler (Exception.class)
public String myExceptionHandler(final Exception e) {
    final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);
    final String strStackTrace = sw.toString(); // stack trace as a string
    logger.error(strStackTrace); // send to logger first
    emailService.sendAlertMail(strStackTrace);
    return "exception"; // default friendly exception message for user
}
```

Comment: But from my service how will I control the exception through this

Comment: Can you show me an example in related to my application as shown above